# Mapping port to access webinterface

Tags: docker, port-forwarding

I have a barebones server, running Linux, but no graphical interface is installed. It's only working in command line and we don't want to change that.

The IP address of this server is `192.168.1.6`

On this machine we run [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) to use multi containers. One of the container is a web app accessible by port `80`.

When I `curl localhost` on my barebones Linux I have the raw data of the webpage. I would like to see the web app from every computer on the same LAN. By example on machine `192.168.1.7`, I would like to type in a browser `192.168.1.6` and see the web app.

First of all, is it possible? If yes, can you provide me some guidelines?

Comment: This shows all the ways - http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/. If you just want to get started see here - https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-access-docker-container-from-another-machine-on-local-network/4737/16.

Comment: Official docs as well - https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this the most straightforward is to use Docker's built in networking.

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
6ef2c6836690        bridge              bridge              local
db24b1e2be58        host                host                local
edf606d533a5        none                null                local
```

By default your container goes into the `bridge` network, unless you tell it otherwise during the `docker run...`.

```
$ docker run -P -d -p 12345:80 nginxdemos/hello
```

Once you do this any host on the LAN can reach it using the IP of the Docker Host + the port:

```
$ curl -I http://192.168.56.101:12345/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.8
Date: Fri, 27 Jul 2018 08:26:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Fri, 27 Jul 2018 08:26:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

#### Firewalls

Keep in mind that you're Docker Host's firewall may be the cause of traffic not ingressing/egressing to/from the Docker container. In some situations, you may need to add the Docker Host's port (12345 in my example above) to an allow list so that hosts outside of Docker Host can access this port.

#### References

- [Connecting Docker Containers, Part One](https://deis.com/blog/2016/connecting-docker-containers-1/)
- [Docker networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/)
- [Docker - Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)
- [How To Set Up a Firewall Using FirewallD on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7)
- [nginx container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)
- [nginxdemos/hello container](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxdemos/hello/)